# how can i get the Response Object in Spring MVC in a normal Bean

Tags: spring

someone could tell me ,how can i get Response in a normal bean in spring, actually,
what i am gonna to do is to create a proxy to check whether a user is log in or not ,if it's not ,i would send him to my home page,if it does,then the request goes to spring mvc's Controller,i know i can get the `HttpServletRequest` Object with declaring the RequestContextListener`in web.xml, i want to get the Response Object, and then i could do the forward  with`RequestDispatcher` .is there a way to get the response object? or you have a solution to this, thanks in advance, i am waiting online ..

Comment: would you want to use a filter for this purpose?

Comment: if i use a filter ,i have to config the mappings ,it'a big job

Comment: In Spring MVC I believe it is called an Interceptor see http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Comment: Why invent your own? Use [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/index.html) I would say.